# Codeception Helper doesn't work

Tags: php, codeception

I'm trying to write a helper for my tests. I has a class generated automatically with `codecept generate:suite api`. I've added the first public function into it, but `codecept build` doesn't add the method to the `ActorActions`.
There are two ways I tryed:

1. Don't add the helper to the config. In this case nothing happens (codeception says "ApiTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added")
2. Add the helper to the config. There is an error "Module \Helper\Api could not be found and loaded"

Here is my config (with helper inside it):

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
            url: 'http://localhost'
            part: [json]
        - Yii2:
            part: [orm, fixtures]
            entryScript: index-test.php
        - \Helper\Api
```

And the helper code is:

```
namespace Helper;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I

use frontend\fixtures\user\oauth\ClientFixture;

class Api extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function authorize(): string
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Codeception version 2.3.8

Comment: What's the path to this helper? It should be saved as tests/_support/Helper/Api.php

Comment: Yes, real path is the same.

Comment: Is the "\" before the "Helper" could be the problem.